# Programmatically using Crashlytics to satisfy GDPR

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I'm about to release a scientific iOS app into the App store, for the first time in a few since years. Since I last released an app, GDPR has happened and I'm wondering about the programming mechanics developers are using to satisfy it:

1. Give the users a choice of enabling Crashlytics/Fabric
2. Turn off Crashlytics without restarting the iOS app? Is that even possible
3. Providing a user button to delete the user's data programmatically - is anyone actually using Crashlytics API to do this
4. The app's backend is Azure based - I don't collect any user data but apparently even Azure collecting IP addresses in a log is sufficient to make my one-person company liable to a fine. Any suggestions how I would programmatically tackle that?

My sense at the moment is to not make my (free) app available in EU territories - Has anyone else given up on EU distribution because of GDPR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i dont have answer to all your questions, but here are some.

1. If you want to give user a choice to enable crashlytics or fabric.

First of all, for initialising crashlytics, you use below code normally as :

```
Crashlytics.start(withAPIKey: kCrashlyticsFabricKey)
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

Now, run this code in selector method of the button that you will provide to enable this in your app.

2. As per my knowledge, turning of Crashlytics is not possible without restarting app. As crashlytics is never used by "Users" of app, it is used by developer of app to get crash data, so it is simple that developer never wants it to turn off, so Crashltics have provided method as `start(withAPIKey:)` but no any stop method, and i think there are very less chance that they will provide such methods in near future.

But yes, you have way to stop submitting report. You can subscribe to `CrashlyticsDelegate`, in which it will give you callback for this method `- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL submit))completionHandler`, here in completionHandler if you provide submit = false, then it will ignore that crash Report.
So, if user have disabled it, then you can stop submitting reports in this way.

3. No idea about this.
4. No idea about this too.

Comment: Fabric/Firebaser here, just wanted to add to this with some more info about number 3: There is no API currently to handle these requests. Right now each request should be sent to support@crashlytics.com. If you'd like to process batch requests or send requests automatically please contact our support team and we can set you up :)

Comment: Kevin, there is an API in Firebase analytics for item #3, correct?